# How to insert an entity into Azure Storage table using Web Activity of Azure Data Factory service

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a table in a storage account. I would like to do a test by inserting an entity into this table using Web Activity with the guide from this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity).
I also tried to create a header in the Web Activity settings with the following format for my shared key (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key):

**Authorization="SharedKey <_AccountName>:<_Signature>"**

But it seems that there is no function in the dynamic expression to make a Hash-based Message Authentication Code (HMAC) for the <_Signature>.
Could someone give me some sample or some hints? Thanks.

Comment: you can also try a function app with javascript runtime and using this [script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8MF9.png) for SharedKeyLite method and this [script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvLUc.png) for just SharedAccess method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a provision for using sha2 encoding in expression builder while using Data Flows.

[image]

But while using web activity in Data factory pipelines you will have to use a workaround. Here is what I tried, Call a serverless function app based on powershell to encode the signature.

basic idea in powershell:

```
$ClearString = "String_to_sign"
    $hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create('sha256')
    $hash = $hasher.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ClearString))

    $hashString = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($hash)
    $body = $hashString.Replace('-', '').ToLower()
```

**1.** **Call the function app:**

With body: a JSON with String_to_sign

```
{
  "name": 'pipeline().parameters.StringToSign'
}
```

[image]

[image]

**2.** **Assign function app output(HMAC) to a variable: (to later encode using base64)**

```
@activity('Azure Function1').output.Response
```

[image]

**3.** **Configure WebActivity as per your scenario:**

**Note: I have used sample data for demonstration purpose**, please use this method modifying as per your need.

Encode HMAC and prep Authorization header by using `base64` function.

```
Authorization: @concat('SharedKey kteststoragee:',base64(variables('sha256')))
```

Build Authorization header following MS doc: [Table service (Shared Key authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#table-service-shared-key-authorization) Use string function such as `Concat` to build the final string.

[image]
[image]

[image]